# ошибка в разметке или в классе

Tags: java, android, разметка

Eclipce выдает такую ошибку в разметке activity_main.xml:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.achess.DrawTest (Open Class, Show Error Log)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse.
```

В layuot должен вызываться класс DrawTest. Читала, что добавление в конструктор класса строки `if(!isInEditMode())   init(context);` должно решить проблему, но 
ява выдает ошибку, что метод init(Context) не доступен для моего класса DrawTest. Подскажите пожалуйста что сделать, чтобы исправить ошибку.

Вот код activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.example.achess.DrawTest
    android:id="@+id/drawTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:minHeight="25dip"
    android:text="Начать сначала"
    android:textStyle="normal" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Код класса DrawTest:

```
 public class DrawTest extends View {        
    Paint p;
    Desc desc1;

    public DrawTest(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) throws SQLException {

      super(context, attributeSet);
      if(!isInEditMode())   init(context);

      p = new Paint();
      DBhelper dbHelper;
      try {         
            int width = 60;
            //для работы с БД         
            dbHelper = new DBhelper(context);   
            desc1 = new Desc(width,width,dbHelper,context); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }


    public void Refresh_Desc(Context context){
        desc1 = null;

        int width = 60;

        DBhelper dbHelper;
        try {
            dbHelper = new DBhelper(context);
            desc1 = new Desc(width,width,dbHelper,context); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        desc1.Draw_desc(p, canvas);
        desc1.Draw_Figures(p, canvas);
        desc1.Draw_Place(p, canvas); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Мы конечно понимаем, что конспирация и всё такое, но хотелось бы видеть весь код View, сомневаюсь, что вы там написали что-то такое, что все вдруг захотят это присвоить

Comment: Вам нужно удалить эту, строку, у вас просто нету этих методов или пишите их сами

Comment: Если ваша View не отображается в Layout, это значит, что у вас не переопределён метод OnDraw()

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, написала сейчас весь класс, раньше описала только конструктор, потому что мне кажется остальное там не важно

Comment: Обманываете, не весь)) К примеру что за поле desc1?)Я не вижу его объявления.

Comment: @Анна я так и не понял где у вас метод init(context), который вы пытаетесь вызвать

Comment: @BORSHEVIK Весь проект лежит тут https://cloud.mail.ru/public/HWVw/iGp5PsdSa . Если интересно и есть время его смотреть). desc1 - это переменная класса Desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотели, чтобы при добавлении вашего View в Layout он отображался в AndroidStudio, то вам необходимо выполнять рисование на канве, которая передаётся в методе **onDraw(Canvas canvas)**, пример

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Log.e(TAG, "onDraw()");
        canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);

        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        if(draw_bend_line){
            Log.d(TAG, "rectangle_current");
            canvas.drawRect(rectangle_current, p);
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "rectangle_first");
            canvas.drawRect(rectangle_first, p);
        }

        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawLine(border_left.x_position, border_left.y_start, border_left.x_position, border_left.y_stope, p);
        canvas.drawLine(border_right.x_position, border_right.y_start, border_right.x_position, border_right.y_stope, p);
    }
```

Собственный пример

Comment: ок я попробую так. Просто у меня при запуске программы белый экран, т.е не работает этот layout. Насколько я поняла из коментариев, вышеуказанная мной ошибка не критична, и белый экран не изза этого? А дело в чем-то другом?

Comment: Наверное не Layout не работает, а ваша View

Answer (score 1):

Указанная ошибка в редакторе eclipse не влияет на программу, а просто не дает просмотреть Graphical Layout в Eclipce. Спасибо всем. Извините, не сразу это поняла.

Answer (score 0):

Ок, давайте по-порядку. С чего вдруг этот init() должен появиться в вашем классе? Где он описан? В классе [View](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html), от которого вы пытаетесь наследоваться, этот метод не описан.

```
public DrawTest(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) throws SQLException {

  super(context, attributeSet);
  if(!isInEditMode())   init(context);

}


public void init(Context context){

  p = new Paint();
  DBhelper dbHelper;
  try {         
        int width = 60;
        //для работы с БД         
        dbHelper = new DBhelper(context);   
        desc1 = new Desc(width,width,dbHelper,context); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: И должен ли? Это просто метод, который был создан автором для удобства, скорее всего там автор инициализирует переменные.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK если это псевдокод, тогда на какую помощь автор надеется? Нужен весь код. Но, цитируя автора: _но ява выдает ошибку, что метод init(Context) не доступен для моего класса DrawTest_ - это не псевдокод

Comment: Наверное вы правы, честно говоря я не понимаю эту строку которую советуют добавлять, просто вычитала про нее несколько раз..  Но как тогда побороть ошибку?

Comment: @Анна ошибка в том, что у вас нет метода, который вы хотите использовать. Напишите его:) Реализуйте какую-то логику в нем, либо  удалите эту строку. Покажите код вашей `View` полностью